# How to get value of textbox on button click on one form and into a string in another class?

Tags: c#, winforms

Not sure how to explain this, I have looked for the past 24 hours on how to figure this out. I just started learning C# this week.

I have one form (Form1) and a class (Class1)

Form1 has a textbox and submit button.

When you click the submit button, I want to send the value in the textbox to the class (Class1) and make it into a string for a mysql query. I already have all of the code for the mysql stuff, but I need to figure out how to get the value in the text box in Form1 into a string in the class file to manipulate the MySQL query.

Comment: Add some code and I'm sure someone will help you out. What have you tried? What does your class look like?

Comment: Where you will use this string later on same form or some other form ?

Comment: Not understanding what you want.

Comment: @MairajAhmad I will be using it in another form that will be created later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the Class created

```
 class MyClass
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

And this the button click event

```
 private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyClass mc=new MyClass ();
            mc.MyProperty = txtMyName.Text;
        }
```

Text box text i am assigning to MyProperty. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I do have another question. How would I pull the value of "MyProperty" in the MyClass class on another form?

Comment: http://goo.gl/i8aKtA this is what you are looking.As you can see in this example MyProperty is made static.

Comment: Thank you for that, I will work on this and reply back shortly!

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm! Thank you for referencing that other question for me and helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely post some code for exact answers. However a general guide is that in the form you will make a new instance of your other class, and then can set values to the properties within that class. Typically you would do that based on a user interface event like a button press, or change event.

```
MyCoolClass something = new MyCoolClass();
something.AProperty = 7;
```

Comment: So what I need to do is create a new instance of the class in the form, then I can set the variable in that class to be used in the actual class? If that makes sense...

Comment: That is exactly correct. You can also then call code in the other class for whatever functionality you need.

Comment: Your insight has helped along with the other guy that posted. Thank you very much for your help.